# How to add an ActionBar above a TabWidget?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-actionbar

I am creating a custom bar above a TabHost. For some reason the custom bar does not appear above the TabHost, instead it is drawn behind it. Not sure why. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!-- 
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/actionbarRelativeLayout">
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/stocktwitsImageButton"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/composeImageButton" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: The TabHost doesn't render any components on screen, that is done by the TabWidget.

Comment: edited question to be more accurate. how can I put something above a TabWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `TabHost` as the root of your layout. Put your `TabHost` inside a `LinearLayout` with `orientation:vertical`.

Then inside the `LinearLayout` and before the `TabHost`, you can put your ActionBar.

Comment: In order to show XML, I need to know: when you talk of ActionBar, do you mean the ActionBar in Honeycomb or just the pattern? In pre-Honeycomb, the Google IO app (http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/activity_track_details.xml) has an example of how to use LinearLayout and a home-made ActionBar.

Comment: im doing a home made action bar. See my relative layout that is commented out.

Comment: @Sheehan Did the Google IO app example above help you further?